# Minimizing a function dealing with seconds and minutes

Tags: php, function, time, minimize

Can I shorten this function?

```
$mins = $secs - time('u');
function minutes($seconds){
return sprintf( "%2.2dm %2.2ds", floor($seconds/60),$seconds%60);}
$mins_left = minutes($mins);
echo "Resets in $mins_left.";
```

Comment: "Unnecessary coding tends to give me headaches"  Unnecessary comments that detract from the essential question give me headaches.  I think it helps to focus on the question without distracting blather.

Comment: Take two aspirin and lie down.

Comment: It's really confusing that you pass a parameter called mins into a function and then refer to it as seconds.

Comment: @Joey:  I care about a clear long-term, enduring, persistent question and a crisp, precise answer.  Personal fluff isn't part of of long-term question that everyone can benefit from.  It's only a "simple question" when you make it simple.  You edit focuses on the question, which is what matters here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I shorten this function?

If for function you're meaning `function minutes($seconds)`, well, I think you can't. if you want to shorten up your whole code, than you could **remove** `minutes` at all, but I don't know if it's okay for you.

```
$mins = $secs - time('u');
$mins_left = sprintf( "%02:%02 mm:ss", floor($mins/60),$mins%60);
echo "Resets in $mins_left.";
```

Considering that's only a sprintf, you could handle it as a **macro**...

Comment: Anyway, $mins and $secs usage is quite disappointing :-) Unclear for a not addicted reader...

Comment: No idea what I was trying to do with the function. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The function minutes() is confusing.

It takes a number of minutes as an argument and return a string with minutes and seconds.

Why then use $seconds within the function?